# Storing dates in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What's the proper way to store dates in Common Lisp? The closest thing I found to an answer is [this](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/dates_and_times.html), which doesn't really seem to cut it for me.

Comment: Where do you want to store them and why `#'get-universal-time` doesn't do whatever you want?

Comment: I just want to store a date in memory, like `(defparameter *my-birth-date* '2/14/1984')`, except I want to do it in whatever the standard way is.

Comment: In what way does the technique listed at your link not work for you?

Comment: I can't see a way there to create and store an arbitrary date.

Comment: See the solution of Ken, using ENCODE-UNIVERSAL-TIME, which is also mentioned on the page you have linked. That's all that is built-in: converting time and date to universal time integers. What other capabilities do you need? If you have other needs for a date storage format, then we need to look for a library that might do what you want...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [`ENCODE-UNIVERSAL-TIME`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_encode.htm)?

```
(defparameter *my-birth-date* (encode-universal-time 0 0 0 14 2 1984))
```

Comment: It's also exactly what's on the page you linked.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a date converted to string, you can use the following:

```
(multiple-value-bind
  (s m h d mm y dw dst-p tz) (get-decoded-time)
     (format nil "~D\/~D\/~D" date month year))
```